# Cephfs: Dynamic provisioning are not working

Tags: kubernetes, cephfs

It's working when I use volumes of cephfs . path is /test and user is test

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cephfs
spec:
  containers:
  - name: cephfs
    image: kubernetes/pause
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/cephfs"
      name: cephfs
  volumes:
  - name: cephfs
    cephfs:
      monitors:
      - 10.16.154.78:6789
      - 10.16.154.82:6789
      - 10.16.154.83:6789
      path: /test
      user: test
      secretRef:
        name: ceph-test
      readOnly: true
```

but it's not working when I create a `StorageClass` like this

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: cephfs
provisioner: ceph.com/cephfs
parameters:
  monitors: 10.16.154.78:6789,10.16.154.82:6789,10.16.154.73:6789
  adminId: test
  adminSecretName: ceph-test
  adminSecretNamespace: default
```

I think there is no support of parameters "path" , how can I transmit path: /test to the `StorageClass` yaml?

Comment: As per the example here: "https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/ceph/cephfs/example" you need to create a pvc using the storage class name and then use the pvc name in your pod volume.

Answer (score 0):

There is `claimRoot`, you can see the usage in this [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/ceph/cephfs/example/class.yaml).

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cephfs
provisioner: ceph.com/cephfs
parameters:
    monitors: 172.24.0.6:6789
    adminId: admin
    adminSecretName: ceph-secret-admin
    adminSecretNamespace: "kube-system"
    claimRoot: /pvc-volumes
```

Also maybe this [blog post](http://d0o0bz.cn/2019/01/cephfs-pv-kubernetes/) might be of help to you.